# IIS6 redirect all requests to home page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis, iis-6

I am trying to get all requests to our ASP MVC site to redirect to the home page. We're moving to a new server, so I set up a redirect/bookmark page inside our `Home/Index.cshtml` file.

I've looked everywhere online and each site I've seen has the same instructions for IIS6:

1. Right click the web site in IIS Manager and go to "Properties"
2. Open up Virtual Directory tab
3. Under "The content for this resource should come from:" select "A redirection to a URL"
4. Paste the URL in the window
5. Under "The client will be sent to:" select "The exact URL entered above" checkbox.

Since I want the user to be redirected to the home page, I pasted the home page link in the window for step 4:

> http://insideapps.dev.shared.com/Tracking

While I can see the URL change appropriately if I try to navigate to any page within the site, the actual home page itself doesn't come up. Just the error message below:

[image]

**EDIT**

Per question in the comments the Virtual Directory tab mentioned in step two posted below

[image]

Comment: which `Open up Virtual Directory tab` did you select?

Comment: Added a screen shot to the post. It's the Virtual directory tab that comes up when you right click the web site and hit "Properties"

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, which virtual directory?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I opened up IIS Manager, expanded the `Web Sites` folder, expanded the domain node (insideapps.dev.shared.com), the right clicked the folder for the web site (Tracking), and selected Properties. Thats's where I found the Virtual Directory tab posted above.

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is if the website that you are redirecting FROM is redirecting to a folder in the SAME website.  Thus a redirect loop.

Comment: Ah, yeah that's exactly what is going on. First time setting something like this up, so not sure how to get around it.

Comment: There isn't *away around it*.

Comment: So I need to set up a completely new site and redirect to that?